# I want to Split the JSON in Java

Tags: java

I have one json as below

```
{"locationType":"City","locationName":[{"id":"161341","name":"Badarganj, Rangpur Division, Bangladesh"}]}
```

I want to split this JSON in 3 parts as below

```
{"locationType":"City"

"locationName":[{"id":"161341"

"name":"Badarganj, Rangpur Division, Bangladesh"}]}
```

I am trying to do like below...But it is not happening

```
String tabValue = "{"locationType":"City","locationName":[{"id":"161341","name":"Badarganj, Rangpur Division, Bangladesh"}]}";
            String[] spiltValue = tabValue.split(",");
            LOGGER.info("spiltValue1 ==== " + spiltValue[2]);
            LOGGER.info("spiltValue2 ==== " + spiltValue[3]);
            LOGGER.info("spiltValue3 ==== " + spiltValue[4]);
```

If I am split with , then it is spliting 4 times...
But I want to split only 3 times.

Can anybody please help here.

Comment: Why don't you just use a JSON parser?

Comment: I am not sure if I can achieve this by JSON parser "or" not.  As currently my requirement is that after splitting this name should like below.                                            communityname[Badarganj, Rangpur Division, Bangladesh]

Comment: I'm sure that that requirement  >can< be achieved using a JSON parser.  Indeed, doing it with a parser will make your code a lot more robust.  Use the right tool.  Don't be afraid to learn.

Comment: can you please provide me some example of JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *limit* parameter, of the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int))* method.

This will stop splitting the value after a specified amount.
The JavaDoc, linked above, has a few examples.

```java
String[] spiltValue = tabValue.split(",", 3);
```

```java
String tabValue = "{\"locationType\":\"City\",\"locationName\":[{\"id\":\"161341\",\"name\":\"Badarganj, Rangpur Division, Bangladesh\"}]}";
String[] spiltValue = tabValue.split(",", 3);
for (String string : spiltValue) System.out.println(string);
```

Output

```
{"locationType":"City"
"locationName":[{"id":"161341"
"name":"Badarganj, Rangpur Division, Bangladesh"}]}
```